# Wrap first n letters of p in span with jquery

Tags: jquery, word-wrap

I need help.

I want the first n (example 200 ) characters of text in specific div to be placed in the **span** and embellish it with CSS, while the 201 character goes normal further and is not in the span.

Now I have this generated HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p> 
</div>
```

I need this;

```
<div class="container">
<p><span class="big">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting</span> industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>    
</div>
```

I have found this http://jsfiddle.net/UX3sC/ but the code duplicates the txt content and I do not need that

```js
var content = $('.content');
content.prepend('<span class="entry-content">' + content.text().substring(0, 200) + '</span><br/><br/>');
```

```css
.entry-content {
  font-size: x-large
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Header</h1>
<span class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque metus est, elementum ut sollicitudin quis, posuere at nisl. Duis venenatis sodales eleifend. Ut pharetra turpis at tortor mattis nec tempus est suscipit. Mauris luctus ante quis justo ornare ornare. Nulla tellus neque, pretium quis pellentesque in, egestas eget erat. Integer id erat semper lectus mollis volutpat. Ut imperdiet massa eget leo pharetra at venenatis turpis posuere. Nullam tempus magna metus, eu ultricies orci. Morbi vulputate aliquet enim vitae bibendum. Duis rutrum mi consequat nisi tempus vehicula. Proin nulla nisi, laoreet et consectetur vitae, scelerisque a justo. Vivamus enim justo, adipiscing at scelerisque at, pulvinar suscipit sem. </span>
```

Comment: Please include your attempts to achieve your goal in the question itself.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: It's really hard to tell where you are stuck,, so the question is too broad. "I need help" is vague.  In jQuery, do you know how to select the element you want? Do you know how to retrieve it's text? Do you know how to process a string in JavaScript? Do you know how to set an element's text in jQuery? These are the basic pieces you need. The online documentation describes all of these. A little Google goes a long way.:)

Comment: @lurker and 90% of that is plain JS

Comment: @mplungjan indeed, lots of simple ways to skin the cat. The op tagged jQuery so I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no other tags in the html of the p, we can do this

```js
var $p = $(".container p");
$p.html(function(_,html) {
  return `<span class="big">${html.substring(0,200)}</span>${html.substring(200)}`
})
```

```css
.big { font-size:x-large }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque metus est, elementum ut sollicitudin quis, posuere at nisl. Duis venenatis sodales eleifend. Ut pharetra turpis at tortor mattis nec tempus est suscipit. Mauris luctus ante quis justo ornare ornare. Nulla tellus neque, pretium quis pellentesque in, egestas eget erat. Integer id erat semper lectus mollis volutpat. Ut imperdiet massa eget leo pharetra at venenatis turpis posuere. Nullam tempus magna metus, eu ultricies orci. Morbi vulputate aliquet enim vitae bibendum. Duis rutrum mi consequat nisi tempus vehicula. Proin nulla nisi, laoreet et consectetur vitae, scelerisque a justo. Vivamus enim justo, adipiscing at scelerisque at, pulvinar suscipit sem. </p> 
</div>
```